# Android count size of INT Array

Tags: android

I have an Array like:

```
 private static int[] f_arme = {
     R.drawable.frankiearmevor_0001, 
     R.drawable.frankiearmevor_0002, 
     R.drawable.frankiearmevor_0003, 
     R.drawable.frankiearmevor_0004, 
     R.drawable.frankiearmevor_0005
```

}

how Do I get the Size of that array (f_arme) ?? = 5
I tried f_arme.size() but get "cannot invoke size() on the array type int[]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the length property:

```
f_arme.length
```